# removeAll function

Tags: trigger

I'm not sure if I'm using the removeAll() function incorrectly or if it's another issue. My current output for this trigger is my products_green__c field being exactly the same as my products_purchased__c field

```
trigger AccGreenProducts on Account (before update) {


    set<string> purchased = new set<string>();
    set<string> red = new set<string>();

    for(account a: trigger.new){
        purchased.add(a.products_purcahsed__c);
        red.add(a.products_red__c);

        set<string> green = purchased.clone();

        //This is where the magic is supposed to happen
        green.removeAll(red);

        //converting green set list to string
        string greenListString= '';

        for(String s: green) {
           greenListString += (greenListString==''?'':',')+s;
        }

        //Assigning value to string field 
        a.Products_green__c = greenList;     

    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @RayDehler See his [previous question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/134407/formula-field-or-trigger) for more insight...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multi-select fields are plain strings joined by semi-colons; you want a Set instead. Here's how you might do that:

```
for(account a: trigger.new) {
    Set<String> red = new Set<String>(), green = new Set<String>();
    if(a.products_purchased__c != null) {
        green.addAll(a.products_purchased__c.split(';'));
    }
    if(a.products_red__c != null) {
        red.addAll(a.products_red__c.split(';'));
    }
    green.removeAll(red);
    a.products_green__c = String.join(new List<String>(green), ';');
}
```